# PHP : Not getting result from MySQL and undefined variable

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am working on a project in which I am getting some information from the database and want to display it inside a form. My SQL query is looking good as I checked it in SQL log, but I am not getting any result from mysql. I want to retrieve value from the database and set it inside a Form. What am I doing wrong with SQL? How can I display the values I read from database and display it inside the form? Thank you.

Code :

```
<?php
      $client_id = $_GET['clientId'];
      $name ="rahul";
      $contact;
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "akshay2787", "tim");
$sql = "select name,contact,tel1,tel2,email1,email2,investment_time,interest,transport,deposit,tax1,tax2,tax3,
 address1,address2,address3,notes from client_setup where client_id='".$client_id."'";
 if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){       
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      $name = $row['name'];
      echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Thank you form is submitted. $name');</script>";
      $contact = $row['Contact'];      
        $tel1 = $row['Telephone1'];      
    }
}

   ?>
///And below I display the values.

<form action="" method="get" align="center" >
 <table  align="center" class="table-block">
<tr class="highlight">
        <td width="100"><label for="netmask">Name</label></td>
        <td width="600"><input class="highlight" type="text" name="Name" id="name"><?php print $name;?></input></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

MYsql logs:

```
2019-02-13T16:27:56.450712Z         4 Query     select name,contact,tel1,tel2,email1,email2,investment_time,interest,transport,deposit,tax1,tax2,tax3,
 address1,address2,address3,notes from client_setup where client_id='6'
```

client_setup table :

```
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| client_setip_id | int(30) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| client_id       | int(30) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name            | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| username        | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password        | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| contact         | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| tel1            | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| tel2            | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email1          | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email2          | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| investment_time | double           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| interest        | double           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| transport       | double           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deposit         | double           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| tax1            | double           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| tax2            | double           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| tax3            | double           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address1        | varchar(500)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address2        | varchar(500)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address3        | varchar(500)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| notes           | varchar(500)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
21 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: `The behaviour of mysqli_num_rows() depends on whether buffered or unbuffered result sets are being used. For unbuffered result sets, mysqli_num_rows() will not return the correct number of rows until all the rows in the result have been retrieved.`. Try using [`fetch_all`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) to get all of the rows and then count them, or use buffered results.

Comment: You really aren't giving yourself space to check for errors in your queries, use mysqli_error() to display if you have an error in your query!!

Comment: Well first of all, are you getting data back with your query? If you do, then I think its your displaying of the code in your input field that is your problem

Answer (score 0):

I think this is where your data isn't displaying

```
 <td width="600"><input class="highlight" type="text" name="Name" id="name"><?php print $name;?></input></td>
```

Supposing your query is correct, it might not display in your input field.

Display it with this instead

```
 <td width="600"><input class="highlight" type="text" name="Name" id="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>"></td>
```

**or**

```
 <td width="600"><input class="highlight" type="text" name="Name" id="name" value="<?=$name?>"></td>
```

Supposing your query isn't working, I'd use this to display the error with the query

```
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
  //Block of code in OP question
}
else{
    echo "Error: ". mysqli_error().". The Query was <br /><pre>$sql</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Silly mistake on my part. During testing, I had changed the clientid in the database. After setting correct clientid, I got the data. Thank you. I am voting to close the question. Thank you everyone.